# Rails Activestorage SFTP File Display Problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sftp

I want to upload the file I upload to the remote server with 'Active Storage'. I used this for [activestorage-ftp](https://github.com/gordienko/activestorage-ftp) gem.

File upload is successful but files are not visible on the page.

File creating at sftp server but I get an error as **'uninitialized constant ActiveStorage::Service::SFTPService::NotConfigured'** when try to see image.

File url seeing like **http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBDZz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--ab0697efaf70339cefdc23b0d5a20501939c14ae/pikachu.jpg**

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voCnS.png)